# Azure Web Sites - Store images in a folder?

Tags: image, azure, web

I have a web app that is configured in the standard Visual Studio project folder model. It has a folder named 'Images' where about 60k of images (mostly jpgs, from 50 - 300k in size) are stored, using about 2 Gb of space.

**Can I use the 'Images' folder in Azure Web Sites just like at a legacy web host**? (The web app runs on a low volume site with large memory spikes when a report with lots of images (uploaded by users) is created as a pdf.)

Comment: You can store the files on Web Sites, but you'll need the Basic tier or higher for that amount of space. It'll be much more economical using blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, you should maybe, however, consider other options for hosting these images. Perhaps Azure Blob Storage, or Amazon S3 could be of use, especially if the images will be viewed by visitors often.